# Connector delete event in anychart gantt component

Tags: events, connector, anychart

I could not find anywhere in the documentation, a way to catch the connector delete event in the gantt component of anychart.
It says in the documentation that in order to delete a connection, select it and press the delete key. but nowhere does it explain us the way to catch that event.
Did I miss out something?

Answer (score 0):

AnyChart Gantt chart has [a multitude of Event Listeners](https://docs.anychart.com/Gantt_Chart/Events#connectors), and it's possible to configure what they handle. There is a deletion Event Listener for the Gantt chart, which is presented below:

```
// add a listener for a connector removal
chart.listen('beforeRemoveConnector', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

We've prepared a basic sample for you to look into: https://playground.anychart.com/VE685L7W/0